# Uncaught TypeError: like is not a function at HTMLSpanElement.onclick. when i click on like its throughting error

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

when i click on like its throughting error

getting error:Uncaught TypeError: like is not a function at HTMLSpanElement.onclick

```
//In Controller
    myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'chatBotService', function($scope, $http, chatBotService) {

        (function () {
            $scope.like = function (lll) {
                alert("like");
                //lll.previousSibling.style.color = 'gray';
                //lll.style.color = 'green';
            }
        });
           (function () {
            $scope.dislike = function (ddd) {
                alert("dislike");
                //ddd.style.color = 'red';
                //ddd.nextSibling.style.color = 'gray';
            }
           });

    function send_message(message) {
          $("#container").append("<div class='row msg_container base_receive'>" +
           "<div class='avatar'>" + "<img src='bot.png' alt='Chat' style='width:15px;margin-right: 10px;'/>" + "<br/>" +"</div>" + "<div class='col-md-10 col-xs-10'>" +"<div class='messages msg_receive'>" + message + "</div>" +"<small>" + DisplayCurrentTime() + "<small/>" + "<span id='dislike' 
    class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down gly-flip-horizontal dislike' onclick='dislike(this)' aria-hidden='true'></span>" + "<span id='like' onclick='like(this)' class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up like' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +  "</div>" + "</div>");
            }

    }]);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: like is not a function
  at HTMLSpanElement.onclick

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: please post your template code. also there is an existing edit for formating your code block, please accept it if the post improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById("dislike").addEventListener("click", dislike);
        document.getElementById("like").addEventListener("click", like);

```
    function dislike() {
        this.style.color = 'red';
        this.nextSibling.style.color = 'gray';
    }

    function like() {         
        this.previousSibling.style.color = 'gray';
        this.style.color = 'green';
    }
```

Comment: now i am getting the function to work but i am getting error like this                    "Uncaught TypeError: like is not a function
    at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick"  but it works fine about is the code i have posted

Comment: I got the problem solved. i was trying to call the function out so i got the error.

Answer (score 1):

remove the closure

```
$scope.like = function (lll) {
    alert("like");
    //lll.previousSibling.style.color = 'gray';
    //lll.style.color = 'green';
}

$scope.dislike = function (ddd) {
    alert("dislike");
    //ddd.style.color = 'red';
    //ddd.nextSibling.style.color = 'gray';
}
```

or change it to IIFE

```
(function () {
    $scope.like = function (lll) {
        alert("like");
        //lll.previousSibling.style.color = 'gray';
        //lll.style.color = 'green';
    }
})();

(function () {
    $scope.dislike = function (ddd) {
        alert("dislike");
        //ddd.style.color = 'red';
        //ddd.nextSibling.style.color = 'gray';
    }
})();
```